# Should variable declarations always be avoided in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, readability, variable-declaration

Sometimes I declare "one use" variables in my code for clarity. Does this affect dramatically the performance or can the compiler optimize it?

For example, I would tend to do:

```
int minVal = long_arithmetic_expresion();
int maxVal = even_longer_expression();

for (int i = minVal; i < maxVal; i++)
    {
        // Do stuff not related to minVal or maxVal
    }

double part1 = 4*sqrt(something)* ... // Very long thing
double part2 = 5*sqrt(something else)* ... // Very long thing

double interestingValue = part1 / part2; // This is the only interesting variable for later
```

Rather than:

```
for (int i = long_arithmetic_expresion(); i < even_longer_expression(); i++)
    {
        // Do stuff not related to minVal or maxVal
    }

double interestingValue = (4*sqrt(whatever)* ...) / (5*sqrt(something else)* ...);
```

This for loop would be contained in a function that will be called many times, so even small performance gain would be relevant in my case.

**Note:**

As it was quickly pointed out, there is a chance that *even_longer_expression()* could be evaluated at every step of the loop, which is of course not good.
For clarity, my question relates to the fact of declaring one-use variables.
I have added a bit more code after the loop. I refer to cases like the variables *part1* and *part2*.

Comment: In your example `int maxVal = even_longer_expression();` only should be declared

Comment: `even_longer_expression()` is going to be evaluated every pass, so of course it makes sense not to have it in there.

Comment: `minVal` and `maxVal` should be `const` or even `constexpr` if it is possible. It not only prevent you from accidentally change their values but also hints compiler to do more optimizations.

Comment: I think the example you really want is one in which your loop conditions are large arithmetic expressions which will not change over the iterations. You'd be best served to edit the question with such an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this affect dramatically the performance or can the compiler optimize it?

Totally depends:

If `long_arithmetic_expresion()` and `even_longer_expression()` are marked as `constexpr` and not likely to change during runtime, the compiler can optimize out recurring calls to these functions.

Otherwise it might be better to use the variables being initialized once.

Comment: Make `maxVal` a `const` in addition. This, then, is also the style traditionally seen with iterator's ends. It prevents re-evaluation on each iteration of the `for` loop with ease.

Comment: @B98 Does this, in short, mean that there is no performance loss in declaring extra variables if they are `const`, but it might be better to avoid extra declarations if they are not `const` ?

Comment: @frischkase Depends on compiler and switches, but while I think that `const` might increase chances of triggering optimization, not declaring a variable and lumping much code together instead looks like premature optimization.  If needed, only the object code will reveal actual requirements, but today's optimizers do follow flows, and optimize.—Both `const` and a variable introduce *names* that can express intent, or abbreviate, `const` adding const-ness to the meaning. I think performance isn't the dominating issue in this case, logic and style might be.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you disable optimizations, the following codes would almost surely show absolutely the same performance on a modern compiler (given that expressions are obviously independent):

```
// save to temporary minVal variable
int minVal = long_arithmetic_expresion();
int maxVal = even_longer_expression();
for (int i = minVal; i < maxVal; i++) {
    ...
}

// avoid creating temporary minVal variable
int maxVal = even_longer_expression();
for (int i = long_arithmetic_expresion(); i < maxVal; i++) {
    ...
}
```

But the first version is often more readable =)

The reason is: [copy propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_propagation) for variables of fundamental types is trivial to do for a compiler. So in the first version compiler would remove `i = minVal` assignment.